# Exposed port shows as filtered when using nmap

Tags: docker, ibm-cloud

I have a container with EXPOSE 27017 in Dockerfile, public ip and published port 27017. There is related info from `ice inspect` output:

```
...
"PortBindings": {
    "27017/tcp": [
        {
            "HostPort": "27017"
        }
    ]
},
...
"NetworkSettings": {
    "Bridge": "",
    "Gateway": "",
    "IpAddress": "172.31.0.16",
    "IpPrefixLen": 0,
    "PortMapping": null,
    "Ports": {
        "27017/tcp": [
            {
                "HostIp": "134.168.18.146",
                "HostPort": "27017"
            }
        ]
    },
    "PublicIpAddress": "134.168.18.146"
},
```

Still, i can't connect to database using public ip, and `nmap` shows port 27017 as filtered.

Is there additional steps to expose container's port?

Comment: What response are you getting when you try to connect? Do the container logs show it started correctly?

Answer (score -1):

It is because when nmap send a packet with SYN flag to the server. It is not responding, but when send SYN to other closed port responds with the flag RST,ACK. Then, the port 27017 is filtered because the firewall (or the own server) are blocking the response packet.

You can check it with *hping*

> $ hping3 -c 3 -S -p 27017 IP